# Execute application on remote computer

Tags: windows, powershell, wmi, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I want to start a process on remote computer(i know administrative credentials of remote computer). for starting a application on remote machine i used

```
    Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\pqr.exe' -ArgumentList '/a' -Verb runas -WindowStyle Normal
```

command with "Invoke-command" or "Enter PsSession" which will start process on remote machine. Now problem is, I am able to start process but soon process starves for CPU allocation(it becomes 0%) and suddenly the launced application become not respoding. Is there any other way to allocate it CPU or run above commandlet with admin rights.

Answer (score 0):

your should start-process then change priority of process 
The command line syntax:

```
wmic process where name="AppName" CALL setpriority ProcessIDLevel
```

Example:

```
wmic process where name="notepad.exe" CALL setpriority 32768
```

or

```
wmic process where name="notepad.exe" CALL setpriority "above normal"
```

> Priority:
>
> idle: 64
>
> below normal: 16384
>
> normal: 32
>
> above normal: 32768
>
> high priority: 128
>
> real time: 256

or use powershell `[System.Diagnostics.ProcessPriorityClass]`
Specify one of the following enumeration values "Normal, Idle, High, RealTime, BelowNormal, AboveNormal"
example

```
$a = (Get-Process -Name powershell)
$a.PriorityClass = [System.Diagnostics.ProcessPriorityClass]::RealTime
```

Comment: The property  "Priorityclass" cannot be found on object

Comment: @kaustubh93 proirtyclass just work on powersehll v4 with .net 4.5 cause off `get-process` see [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849832.aspx)... but wmi query should work for you

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

[PsExec](https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx)

Maybe this work for you